# What’s the difference between KVStore and KVEngine in NebulaGraph Database？

Tags: nebula-graph

Nebula Graph version: 3.3

I’ve been checking the source code of the NebulaGraph Database and have gotten confused about the relationship and the difference between KVStore and KVEngine. KVEngine implements `RocksEngine.cpp` to access rocksdb， while KVStore seems more like a logical concept, and all kinds of CRUD are executed through KVStore. So, how KVstore interacts with the underlying database?

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

- KVEngine is the abstract of the key-value engine per single(server) storage instance, and RocksEngine is one of its implementations.
- KVStore is the abstract of the general Storage layer (as you mentioned, logical), i.e. the Distributed Consensus + KVEngine together construct the KVStore. NebulaStore is one of its implementations.